# Is there a way to have an inherited method perform a check, then refer back to the original method if the check fails? (Python)

Tags: python, class, inheritance, methods, overriding

Let's say I have a Parent class and a child class that looks like this:

```
class Parent():
 def __init__(self,value):
     self.value = self.value
 def get_value(self):
     return self.value

class Child(Parent):
 def __init__(self,value):
     super(Child,self).__init__(value)
 def get_value(self):
     if self.value == 10
        print("Yay!")
     else:
        Parent.get_value()
```

So like the above, I want to have a subclass of a parent class that overrides an inherited method from the parent class, but I want it to check for a specific condition. If that specific condition isn't met (in this case self.value = 10) then just run the method from the parent class.

EDIT: Fixed a syntax error

Comment: You can use either 1) `Parent.get_value(self), or 2) super().get_value()`.   [Reference](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-call-parent-class-method/)

Comment: FYI: `if self.value = 10` is a syntax error, I think you want `if self.value == 10:`

Comment: Great thanks so much!

Comment: Also in Python 3 you can just use `super().__init__(value)` rather than `super(Child,self).__init__(value)` (i.e. Python 3 removed the need to specify the classname).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like that

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def get_value(self):
     print(f'parrent {self.value}')
     return self.value





class Child(Parent):
 def __init__(self,value):
     super(Child,self).__init__(value)
 def get_value(self):
     if self.value == 10:
        print(f'child {self.value}')
        print("Yay!")
     else:
        super().get_value()




c = Child(10)
c.get_value()

cp = Child(11)
cp.get_value()
```

output

```
child 10
Yay!
parrent 11
```